# How to get Page ID from Facebook Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe

After I installed the [iframehost](https://apps.facebook.com/iframehost/) app and edited content. The app how to know my page id and render the content successfully. I want to make an app such as it.

**My problem is**: Assume  many users installed my App for their page, but I don't know how to get the page id  from different Iframe for each request the page.  Please, who can explain how to get page id from iframe when users enter the Facebook page tab.

Comment: It is included in the signed request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Page ID with the signed_request parameter. Here are some threads where this is explained already:

- [Facebook API get Fanpage ID inside Page Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776809/facebook-api-get-fanpage-id-inside-page-tab)
- [Get Facebook Page Tab ID of current Tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311525/get-facebook-page-tab-id-of-current-tab)
- [how to get facebook page id inside page fan tab using facebook javascript sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887687/how-to-get-facebook-page-id-inside-page-fan-tab-using-facebook-javascript-sdk)
- [How can I find out what Page has installed my Facebook App / which page is loading my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587784/how-can-i-find-out-what-page-has-installed-my-facebook-app-which-page-is-loadi)